# Why __attribute((constructor)) works, and __attribute((constructor(100))) doesn't (seg fault) using clang++ 17.0.1

Tags: c++, clang++

I am experimenting with the `constructor` attribute provided in clang (clang++ here). When I do:

```
#include <iostream>

__attribute__((constructor)) void RegistryFunction();

void RegistryFunction() {
    std::cerr << "working" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    std::cerr << "Main function running." << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It compiles and runs fine

```
clang++ -std=c++23 -c test.exe text.cc
```

But if I use `constructor(100)` (setting up a priority, which can be 0 or anything else) like that, it seg-faults.

I am on clang 17.0.1 (on Windows). Do you know why setting the priority number would cause the app to crash?

Comment: If you set a priority but keep the body of the function empty, does it crash?

Answer (score 4):

There is a good chance that std::err is not initialized during this phase. Don't use `iostream` for constructor functions. Use `printf` family. The C-Runtime is initialized by the time constructor functions are called.

Comment: Yes, you are on the right track. If I comment std::cerr out, indeed, it runs even with constructor(100). However, I don't accept this as the answer because it doesn't explain why using std::cerr and `constructor()` without setting a priority works. I guess it could have to do with the fact that adding a priority triggers RegistryFunction to be called before std::cerr is initialized (while std::cerr is initialized before when no prio is set). Could be.

Comment: @user18490  Google _"static initialisation order fiasco"_ what is happening with the different priorities is changing when the function is called relative to statically initialised  objects (eg `std::cerr`),

Comment: The C++ standard does not talk about `__attribute__((constructor))`, so there is no guarantee that `std::cerr` will be constructed at what priority level. If you want to find that out you will have to go look at the `clang` linker source code for your specific platform or look at the `.init` section of your code. Sure, you don't have to say you don't accept the answer. You didn't mark it as such means you don't. Someone else might have a better answer for you.